# C++ replace_if on vector with struct in STL

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was looking for a way to use std::replace_if updating my current structure in the vector, and not creating a new object.

For example

```
std::vector<setting> settings;

// ... add stuff to settings

setting newsetting;     
std::string name = "something";

std::replace_if(settings.begin(), settings.end(), [&](setting const& v)
{
    return v.name == name;
}, newsetting);
```

In this case I need to use newsetting, is there any way I can reference my existing vector and update the value in there? I looked up this problem already but only found a solution in boost, I want to do this strictly in STL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like you need anything more fancy than garden-variety range iteration:

```
std::vector<setting> settings;

for (auto &one_setting:settings)
{
    if (one_setting.name == name)
    {
         one_setting.a_method_that_changes_this_setting_somehow();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a STL solution and was trying to not do this, but this works anyway. Thanks.